# Connect multiple entities to a locations entity that has a composite primary key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have some entities that define the locations such that:

**Cities**

```php
/**
 * cities
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cities")
 */
class cities
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="lang", type="string", length=5)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $lang;

    /**
     * @var \Provinces
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provinces")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_province", referencedColumnName="id"),
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lang", referencedColumnName="lang")
     * })
     */
    private $idProvince;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_region", type="integer")
     */
    private $idRegion;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_country", type="integer")
     */
    private $idCountry;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var geometry
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="chords", type="geometry", nullable=false)
     */
    private $chords;
    
    // ... getters and setters
}
```

This is followed by the entity of provinces, regions and countries that have a similar structure. Since each city has an ID, I create an ID-LANG composite index, in which I have a city, for example Madrid, with the ID: 125 and this one in five languages:

- ID: 125 LANG: ES
- ID: 125 LANG: EN
- ID: 125 LANG: FR
- ID: 125 LANG: PT
- ID: 125 LANG: IT

This entity will be connected to all the entities in which you need to save an address. And to be able to use the different languages, I don't use the name of the city, but rather I use its ID and show the name based on the language the user navigates in.

An example of an entity in which I need the address is for example the Business entity:

```php
/**
 * Empresas
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="business")
 */
class Business
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_city", type="integer")
     */
    private $idCity;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_province", type="integer")
     */
    private $idProvince;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_region", type="integer")
     */
    private $idRegion;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_country", type="integer")
     */
    private $idCounry;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="img", type="string", length=250)
     */
    private $img;

    /**
     * @var Cities
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Cities", mappedBy="id") || @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cities", mappedBy="id")
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var Provinces
     */
    private $province;

    /**
     * @var Regions
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @var Countries
     */
    private $country;
}
```

As you can see in my code I try to connect the $city property with the Cities entity to obtain all the city data.

I don't care if it has to be OneToOne to get and have the city data already in their language or if it should be OneToMany and then search within the ArrayCollection for the language corresponding to the user.

What I would like is for it to be unidirectional from Business to Cities since if I do it bidirectional (in this case I have no problems) a large amount of data accumulates and I also have to be introducing a property in the city entity for each entity that connects to the cities entity. Since the entity of cities will also be connected to other entities such as Users, Clients, Workers, etc ...

Comment: This all feels very strange. You created a composite key just because of translations? You're letting view determine what your business model should look like. Translations really should have been a separate table that would be referenced when fetching a name to display.

Comment: @El_Vanja I may be putting it wrong from the start, you're right. Could you explain a little more what would be your way of doing it?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could completely omit the name from the city model/table and have a translation table hold all the variants. You could organize it as a OneToMany (one city, many translations). You might keep a name in a default language inside the city model/table, but that's entirely up to you and the way your application is used (depends on just how often that default would be used).

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks for your answer, I will study what you say. Likewise, there is no way with Doctrine to make the owner entity connect with the cities entity without it being bidirectional?